# Issue with android Recyclerview adapter in JSON Parsing using volley

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-volley

I am new to android development and recently working on a so called covid tracker app.
I ran into the issue of recyclerview "no adapter attached skipping layout". I'm using volley library for networking and parsing the data straight into my app. the json part is working absolutely fine, but the real issue I'm facing is my app crashes after opening and recyclerview is not showing any data.
My code goes like this:

This is the Mainactivity class:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private RecyclerView mRecyclerview;
private ExampleAdapter mExampleAdapter;
private ArrayList<exampleItem> mExampleList;
RequestQueue requestQueue;



protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    mRecyclerview = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    mRecyclerview.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mRecyclerview.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    mExampleList = new ArrayList<>();


    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    fetchdata();



}
public  void fetchdata(){
    String url = "https://api.rootnet.in/covid19-in/stats/latest";
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new 
Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

            try {
                JSONObject data = response.getJSONObject("data");
                JSONArray regionalArray = data.getJSONArray("regional");
                for (int i = 0; i < regionalArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject statewise = regionalArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    String statename = statewise.getString("loc");
                    int totalconfirmed = statewise.getInt("totalConfirmed");
                    int discharged = statewise.getInt("discharged");
                    int death = statewise.getInt("deaths");
                    mExampleList.add(new exampleItem(statename,totalconfirmed,discharged,death));
                    Log.i("list",statename+totalconfirmed+discharged+death);

                }
                Log.i("list", mExampleList.toString());
                mExampleAdapter = new ExampleAdapter(MainActivity.this, mExampleList);
                mExampleAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                mRecyclerview.setAdapter(mExampleAdapter);



            } catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
}
}
```

This is my adapter class:

```
public class ExampleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ExampleAdapter.ExampleViewHolder> {

private Context mContext;
private ArrayList<exampleItem> mExampleList;

public ExampleAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<exampleItem> exampleList){
    mContext=context;
    mExampleList=exampleList;}

@NonNull
@Override
public ExampleViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.covid_data_layout,parent,false);
    return  new ExampleViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ExampleViewHolder holder, int position) {
    exampleItem currentItem = mExampleList.get(position);

    String stateName = currentItem.getState();
    int confirmed = currentItem.getConfirmed();
    int recovered = currentItem.getRecovered();
    int death = currentItem.getDeath();

    holder.statetextView.setText(stateName);
    holder.confirmedtextview.setText(confirmed);
    holder.recoveredTextView.setText(recovered);
    holder.deathtextView.setText(death);
    holder.activeTextView.setText(confirmed-recovered-death);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mExampleList.size();
}

public class ExampleViewHolder extends  RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    public TextView statetextView;
    public TextView confirmedtextview;
    public TextView recoveredTextView;
    public TextView deathtextView;
    public TextView activeTextView;

    public ExampleViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        statetextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.state_textView);
        confirmedtextview = itemView.findViewById(R.id.confirmed_textView);
        recoveredTextView= itemView.findViewById(R.id.recovered_textView);
        deathtextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.death_textView);
        activeTextView= itemView.findViewById(R.id.active_textView);

    }
}
}
```

this is my javaclass for information:

```
public class exampleItem {
private String mState;
private int mConfirmed;
private int mRecovered;
private int mDeath;

public  exampleItem(String state, int confirmed,int recovered,int death){
    mState=state;
    mConfirmed=confirmed;
    mRecovered=recovered;
    mDeath=death;
}

public String getState(){
    return mState;
}
public int getConfirmed(){
    return mConfirmed;
}

public int getRecovered(){
    return mRecovered;
}

public  int getDeath(){
    return mDeath;
}
}
```

For any help, i'll be extremely grateful.
Thank you!

Comment: Pls post *crash log* here.

Comment: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<androidx.core.view.ViewCompat$2>: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/view/View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener;       Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.failiure-K-L7zQKwOlHb5Nha7WM-Cw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.failiure-K-L7zQKwOlHb5Nha7WM-Cw==/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]

Comment: Call `notifyDataSetChanged` after setting the adapter. Not before. And when you first create and set the adapter `notifyDataSetChanged` is not needed. Only when you update the adapter

Comment: Didn't worked!!  Same set of issues again

Comment: Not sure how much you paid for this, but that doesn't seem to be worth. Please try with the following changes:
In fetchData() function, remove the line mExampleAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: @RahulShukla Bruh i havent paid yet! XD BTW thanks

Comment: Thanks to everyone you showed interest in my issue. It finally worked.

Comment: :D nice to hear that... sounds your issue got resolved. Please don't forget to post the answer and accept the same as a solution so someone else can take a benefit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove **mExampleAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();** from your MainActivity and in Adapter calss update the code onBindViewHolder like this.

```
String stateName = mExampleList.get(position).getState();
int confirmed = mExampleList.get(position).getConfirmed();
int recovered = mExampleList.get(position).getRecovered();
int death = mExampleList.get(position).getDeath();

holder.statetextView.setText(stateName);
holder.confirmedtextview.setText(String.valueOf(confirmed));
holder.recoveredTextView.setText(String.valueOf(recovered));
holder.deathtextView.setText(String.valueOf(death));
holder.activeTextView.setText(String.valueOf(confirmed-recovered-death));
```

Comment: Thankkkkk you very much brother...! Love you